# Can big ViewState content result a HTTP Error 504 - Gateway timeout?

Tags: .net, asp.net, http, viewstate, http-status-code-504

I have one asp.net page which seems to return a very big content (5,648,733 bytes and that is

mostly consumed by VIEWSTATE) ending with a 504 Gateway timeout error. I am tracking the http

request/response by using Fiddler.

And basically, when I post-back the same page -by clicking a button- the post-back fails with thoose errors shown in IE and in FF:

> Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage --> **in IE**
>
> The connection to the server was reset
>   while the page was loading. --> **in FF**

*Question*: **Can this be because of the big size injected in VIEWSTATE; and if yes, what is the main 
reason so that it loads the page but cannot post the page back after?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if you are hitting the [MaxRequestLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) of the application; Default is 4MB.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Chris Shaffer!

After you point me out that I have changed the MaxRequestLength of the application by adding this line to my web.config:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="60240"/>
```

And tested the page to see whether it works. And it did!

So, now I have to find a way to reduce ViewState of the GridView on that page.

Answer (score 0):

There are many places where a request can timout. The timeout will occurr in the link in the chain that has the lowest timeout.

You should check if you have any proxy settings in IE.