# IIS 8.5 connection timeout is _always_ 60 seconds

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have an ASP.NET application running on IIS 8.5 that times out at 60 seconds regardless of what I set. In other words, I can set the connection timeout to 300 seconds or 30 seconds and the page will still time out at 60 seconds. The Request status code is `504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT`.

Site:

- Connection timeout = 300 seconds (5 mins)
- Session timeout = 20 minutes
- Script timeout = 10 minutes

App Pool:

- .NET CLR v4.0
- Integrated pipeline
- 64-bit (32-bit not allowed)
- Idle timeout = 20 mins (default)

Other things I've done:

- Read just about every article I can on this subject
- Set the `executionTimeout` in my web.config
- Restarted the site or ran `iisreset` after each change
- Disabled all sites except this one to isolate it
- Created a simple ASPX page in which I set a Sleep thread to under or over 60 seconds, and tried every combination with the connection timeout value.

I'm at a loss. Any ideas?

Comment: _Read just about every article_ if so, read another one [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @AleksAndreev: What else would you have had me provide?

Comment: @opus4210 did you get the answer? Even I am facing same issue

Answer (score 5):

The answer turned out to be a load balancer, which I was unaware existed, that had its own timeout setting.

Comment: Same happen on my case, I had an AWS load balancer with 60 seconds idle timeout.

Comment: I may cry.  worked on this 100 hours and some AWS angels came and increased the 60s timeout and it worked!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Check your maxRequestLength, apparently that can cause a 504 if the incoming request exceeds the default limit of 4MB.

[504 Error On Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985971/504-error-on-server)

[Can big ViewState content result a HTTP Error 504 - Gateway timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194741/can-big-viewstate-content-result-a-http-error-504-gateway-timeout)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This isn't the issue because the problem happens with the test app that I mentioned above, which has a request length of only a couple of K.

Comment: It takes longer than 60 seconds to send a few kilobytes? Are you using a dial-up connection?

Comment: No, the test is purposely creating the delay of 60+ seconds with a Sleep thread.